# Can i change node in 3rd line to node_new or something else?

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list

```
struct node
{
int data;
node *next;
};
```

This is the code used for defining a structure in linked list. Can we replace node *next in 3rd line by node_new *next or something else?

Comment: You may. But now it's no longer pointing to another `node`.

Comment: my doubt is I am felling it as some kind of recursion in itself. We are defining the structure node which contains some data and pointer to node itself. How is that possible?

Comment: It's not recursive. You can create pointers to objects the moment you know the name of their type. The definition need not even be present. `struct node; node* p = nullptr;` is perfectly valid. It's the same here.

Comment: Make a google research about "incomplete types". They may not be used as itself but using a pointer to them is allowed. As you did it it's usually done (even in C). If you have two `struct`s referring to each other - a "forward declaration" helps which produces an "incomplete type" as well.

Answer (score 0):

> Can we replace `node *next` in 3rd line by `node_new *next` or something else?

By keeping the other parts of the struct as is, *no*, since it wouldn't achieve what you probably want.

You need to understand what your struct means:

```
struct node     // this is the type of the node
{
   int data;    // data of node
   node *next;  // pointer to the next node (thus the type has to match)
};
```